# How to add multiple captured images into a group cell template in dxdatagrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

The requirement is to capture multiple images to each of the group cell template in dxDataGrid.

[image]

Single image capture is performed as shared in below screenshot , I need it for multiple images within same grouped cell.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to capture multiple images within a grouped cell in dxdatagrid. but it doesn't work for some reason.